# io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security, jwt, jjwt

I am using spring boot and spring security with JWT on rest service. I used the code in below link:
https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt-mysql
And it works fine but when we use its token for authentication and ... We face the below error:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:354) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.isan.config.JwtTokenUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.isan.config.JwtTokenUtil.getClaimFromToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.isan.config.JwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.isan.config.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
```

These are the codes:

1-WebSecurityConfig class:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register").permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

2-JwtTokenUtil class:

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2550185165626007488L;

    public static final long JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY = 5 * 60 * 60;

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;

    //retrieve username from jwt token
    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    //retrieve expiration date from jwt token
    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    //for retrieveing any information from token we will need the secret key
    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret.getBytes()).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    //check if the token has expired
    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }

    //generate token for user
    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    //while creating the token -
    //1. Define  claims of the token, like Issuer, Expiration, Subject, and the ID
    //2. Sign the JWT using the HS512 algorithm and secret key.
    //3. According to JWS Compact Serialization(https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-41#section-3.1)
    //   compaction of the JWT to a URL-safe string 
    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY * 1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret.getBytes()).compact();
    }

    //validate token
    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

3-JwtRequestFilter class:

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
        // only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }

        // Once we get the token validate it.
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
            // authentication
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
                // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

4-JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint class:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7858869558953243875L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

5-JwtAuthenticationController class:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class JwtAuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
                .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveUser(@RequestBody UserDTO user) throws Exception {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userDetailsService.save(user));
    }

    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
        }
    }
}
```

6-JwtUserDetailsService class:

```
@Service
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        DAOUser user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                new ArrayList<>());
    }
    
    public DAOUser save(UserDTO user) {
        DAOUser newUser = new DAOUser();
        newUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        newUser.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        return userDao.save(newUser);
    }
}
```

7- application.properties

```
jwt.secret=javainuse
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/bootdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=asdasdasd
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

8-pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.javainuse</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-jwt</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

9-token example:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzYW0iLCJleHAiOjE2MDgwNjM1NTUsImlhdCI6MTYwODA0NTU1NX0.X77D8mceGbBWRCWUOwhL-5iwpZQqFAITmQqOW_s48vGDkkWdMFg1dm_Gackri8evPVzkF6lt2tXvHCbOlpe86w
```

10-secret example:

```
javainuse
```

Comment: wrong key/secret during verification?

Comment: thanks for your answer but as i debug the code the key/secret are the same!

Comment: Ok. I add the code. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

In JwtTokenUtil class, just change below methods:

```
private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
        .parseClaimsJws(token.replace("{", "").replace("}","")).getBody();
}

private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
    return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims)
        .setSubject(subject)
        .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY * 1000))
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512,
                  secret.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))).compact();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, we need verify our Auth token, while generating auth token in case of signup or signin API call we should not pass the token in postman request headers. Please be sure in Authorisation tab select type as "No Auth" for above APIs I mentioned.